# NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED while trying to write text to file from Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to write text to file by using the code example from [here](http://openwritings.net/public/firefox-extension/write-text-file-your-extensions-folder) and it is giving me the NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED while getting the extension manager. This is my first try with a Firefox extension and i have no idea what is wrong. Please can someone help me. Here is a screenshot of the console.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be making the wrong assumption here, but your code sample will only work with Firefox versions 4 and older.
So you might want to take a look at a more up to date reference like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O

If I made the wrong assumption please tell us a bit more.

Comment: i think this is the right answer, i was at the latest version and i ditched the the code and got it working for the time being. Thanx alot.